# Windows 7 - Windows Security "Enter your credentials" box doesn't have any options inside

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have been experiencing this issue with a few machines in our organisation. Certain machines when having to enter credentials for providing admin rights, signing into Lync/Outlook, or anything that requires you to sign in, will show up as blank. The usual fix for this would have been to just delete the user profile through registry and their C:\Users*USERNAME* folder. This has not been working lately.

I was just wondering if there was a way to resolve this without having to completely rebuild the machine. The expected result is for the credentials window to appear with at least the user's username and domain, a "Use another account" option, and a smart card option (organisation specific configuration).

Does anyone have any suggestions on getting this fixed? Please leave comments if you need any further information.

Comment: are you using some sort of card reading software for smart cards? how do your users normally log into their profiles?

Comment: @mael' yeah we are. They log in with Windows credentials from AD. Standard signing in procedures. The only difference is that Smartcard software is used for Smartcard purposes.

Comment: just out of curiosity - if you're using third-party card reading software I would try uninstalling it and seeing if you get your normal credential pop-up back. I've seen programs like ActivClient hose up the entire credential store and it can prevent you from getting a lot of different things done.